# read permission denied using NTFS when I denied write permission

Tags: c#, permissions, ntfs

Using the below code I denied write permission for a user, even when I checked security tab only write permission is denied, but I'm not able to access the folder for reading.

```
ADsSecurity objADsSec;
SecurityDescriptor objSecDes;
AccessControlList objDAcl;
AccessControlEntry objAce1;
AccessControlEntry objAce2;
Object objSIdHex;
ADsSID objSId;

objADsSec = new ADsSecurityClass();
objSecDes = (SecurityDescriptor)(objADsSec.GetSecurityDescriptor("FILE://" + vPath));
objDAcl = (AccessControlList)objSecDes.DiscretionaryAcl;

objSId = new ADsSIDClass();
objSId.SetAs((int)ADSSECURITYLib.ADS_SID_FORMAT.ADS_SID_SAM, UserName.ToString());
objSIdHex = objSId.GetAs((int)ADSSECURITYLib.ADS_SID_FORMAT.ADS_SID_SDDL);



objAce2 = new AccessControlEntryClass();
objAce2.Trustee = (objSIdHex).ToString();
objAce2.AccessMask = (int)ActiveDs.ADS_RIGHTS_ENUM.ADS_RIGHT_GENERIC_WRITE;
objAce2.AceType = (int)ActiveDs.ADS_ACETYPE_ENUM.ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED;
objAce2.AceFlags = (int)ActiveDs.ADS_ACEFLAG_ENUM.ADS_ACEFLAG_INHERIT_ACE | 1;
objDAcl.AddAce(objAce2);

objSecDes.DiscretionaryAcl = objDAcl;

// Set permissions on the NTFS file system folder.
objADsSec.SetSecurityDescriptor(objSecDes, "FILE://" + vPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing objAce1

You need to order Deny ACE entries *before* Grant ACE entries.

Try swapping the order of entries in the ACL.

> Thus, the DACL's list of ACEs should be appropriately ordered. The standard (canonical) ordering is to first place explicit denies, then explicit allows, general (group) denies, and group allows. If the canonical ordering isn't used, unanticipated allows or denies may occur

From [Understanding Windows File And Registry Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc982153.aspx)

Comment: i did not use objAce1, i commented that block, so before denying write, what i need to do, allow read??

Comment: you need to do **nothing** before denying (at least not within the same ACL. Inherited entries don't count IIRC - see the linked article)